# duplicating of username after minimizing the terminal beyond the length of the username

Tags: command-line, 20.04, lts

[Image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q54dF.png)

Whenever the terminal size is reduced to wrap the terminal promt, it seems to replicate the promt many times.
This is not a one time thing, it is repeatable(u can keep going).

System :
Virtual machine - **vmware**
running **Ubuntu
20.04.3 LTS**

Comment: Did you try the `reset` command?

Comment: I tried it but it didn't seem to work, it replicates just like before

Comment: when i tried `reset` again it only worked for few seconds after which it replicates like before

Comment: It seems to me like a bug. I can replicate the same problem in 22.10 also.